# Combine and sort two arrays of different length in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am looking for a solution for my 'problem', that isn't an ugly hack.

In my Java code I have two arrays, both of an unknown length (so they will probably be of different length).
I would like to sort them like this:

```
Array A: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Array B: {6, 7, 8}

New Array: {1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 5}
```

Is there a nice way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: In what way is this sorted? Looks like just zipped together (in the respective original order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is likely that there are many more in one array than the other, it should be faster to zip the first part and then bulk copy the rest using `System.arrayCopy`. It also simplifies dasblinkenlight's `for` loop by removing the `if`s.

```
int[] res = new int[a.length + b.length];
int p = 0;
//zip what we can
int last = Math.min(a.length, b.length);    
for (int i = 0; i != last; i++) {
    res[p++] = a[i];
    res[p++] = b[i];
}
//now add the remaining
int aRemain = a.length - last;
if(aRemain > 0) {
  System.arrayCopy(a, last, res, p, aRemain);
}
else
{
  int bRemain = b.length - last;
  if(bRemain > 0) {
    System.arrayCopy(b, last, res, p, bRemain);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
int[] res = new int[a.length + b.length];
int p = 0;
int last = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
for (int i = 0 ; i != last ; i++) {
    if (i < a.length) res[p++] = a[i];
    if (i < b.length) res[p++] = b[i];
}
```

Comment: First time I have ever seen `i != last`. Any reason for this over the more idiomatic `i < last`?

Comment: +1. Even though the argument does not seem to apply when the iteration counter is locally scope to just the loop. But probably a useful habit to get into for other situations (like in Javascript which does not have block-scope).

Comment: I actually thought about doing this myself a couple of times, but was always worried that if for some reason the counter "skips ahead" too far, making me "miss the exit", then I end up with a practically infinite loop.