# How can i concatenate char[]

Tags: java, android

Let's say I have

```
Char[] one = {'a','b'};
Char[] two = {'c','d'};
```

What do I need to concatenate them?

Some code:

```
Random rand = new Random();

int Plength = 6;
char[] i = new char[Plength];
for (int x = 0; x < Plength; x++){
    i[x] = one[rand.nestIng(one.length)];
}
```

Comment: Define "connect". What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine and sort two arrays of different length in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952127/combine-and-sort-two-arrays-of-different-length-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to concatenate two arrays:

```
char[] array1 = ...
char[] array2 = ...

char[] result = new char[array1.length + array2.length];
System.arraycopy(array1, 0, result, 0, array1.length);
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, result, array1.length, array2.length);
```

`result` contains a concatenation.